# HTTP header 'Connection: Close' not sent by IE

Tags: internet-explorer, http, sockets, protocols

I have a custom HTTP server that implements the HTTP 1.1 protocol.

I have no problem using persistent connections, however, I never receive 'Connection: Close' from IE ( I haven't tested other browsers. )  Instead, the 'receive' times out because it seems IE closes the connection.

What header from IE should I look for to gracefully close the connection?

Comment: Connection: close is an indicator that the client doesn't intend to reuse the connection for subsequent requests. You should not expect to receive this header. If you don't want to allow keep-alive, then you should simply send Connection: close in the response headers, and then close the connection after returning the response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setting of the "Connection" header in 1.1 is "keep-alive" when the header is not present.  IE does not close the connection right away so it can utilize the same connection for subsequent requests, and then closes the connection after a timeout if you do not send any requests right away.

Comment: So, should I send a '100 - continue' or just let the connection timeout?

Comment: You can only send a `100` reply if the client explicitally asks for it via an `Expect: 100-continue` header, and even then only in reply to a request that is pending.  So you will just have to let your connection timeout normally.  Like I said, even IE does not know right away whether a connection is going to be re-used or not, so it does not send a `Connection: close` header for HTTP 1.1 requests

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to have browser explicitly send Connection: Close. And it does timeouts in 60 seconds, which is defined in registry.

I don't see a problem to gracefully handle "manual" client disconnect.

Comment: It's not that it's a problem, as you word it.  It's that it would be nice if it could be done gracefully.  If that's not possible then I guess it's not a problem ;)

Comment: Well, even if browser would always send that, you will still need to handle the situation when connection drops gracefully.